# How to convert TortoiseSVN to TortoiseGit

Tags: windows-xp, version-control, tortoise-svn, tortoise-git

I am currently using TortoiseSVN for version control. I want to convert to Git so I though TortoiseGit would be the easiest move.

How do I convert my repository to a Git one while preserving all history?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `git-svn`. There are detail instructions [here](http://github.com/guides/import-from-subversion). This doesn't have anything to do with Tortoise, though.

Comment: I feel a schmuck for not finding this with Google. I'll give it a look. Thanks.

Comment: TortoiseGit supports git-svn now, including cloning SVN repos.